# Google Sheets Apps Script: Update todays date in column A when editing in colums B-G

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to get Column A to update todays date when editing in columns D-G (and only columns D-G)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HH4L.png) completely new to scripting.

the code is not complete and i am getting errors so i realize im missing something

Comment: e.range.columnStart and e.range.columnEnd return 'column number', that ```B``` and ```G``` you used in your code are undefined, if you want B and G column as range, in most cases you should pass them as string (```"B", "G"```) to a function, the way you used ```B``` and ```G``` 
 in your code is trying to call a variable value named ```B``` and ```G```, the same concept as you called ```sh``` later in the code, but you have never declared them, so the value is undefined. In this case, you should use ```2``` and ```7``` instead, because B is the 2nd column, and G is the 7th column.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of corrections to make:

1. set the event constant/variables BEFORE checking "if" the event met parameters.
2. instead of checking if a range starts and ends at certain columns, check if the event occurred within a range.
3. use the rowIndex of the event instead of the rowStart.

Here is script that will check if edit event occurred after row 1 (a header row) and BETWEEN columns B and G:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = sh.getActiveCell();
  if (r.getRow() > 1 && r.getColumn() > 1 && r.getColumn() < 8) {
  sh.getRange("A" + r.getRowIndex()).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM");}}
```